# How to write a post call in an angular service

Tags: angular, typescript, http, angular7, angular-services

I have a service that takes my input as below,

```
{
  "overviewPreferences": {
    "selectedRole": [{
      "code": "PRACTITIONER"
    }],
    "selectedDomainList": [{
      "code": "2",
      "name": "HR"
    },
    {
      "code": "3",
      "name": "PAYROLL"
    }]
  }
}
```

I declared my interface as follows,

```
export interface UserDomain {
  code: string;
  value: string;
  selected: boolean;
}
```

My service,

```
updateUserSelectedDomains(code: String): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post<UserDomain>(`/adpi/rest/core/v2/business-intelligence/workers/${aoId}/preferences") `, request)
    .pipe(
      map(data => this.data = data),
    );  
}
```

Here I want know what should be the interface?Is it the request I am sending or the response I am getting.I am not sure whether I did it correctly.can anyone please review my code.Thanks.

Comment: It is the response you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

```
post<ResponseType>
```

Strongly types the observable that is returned. So calling this method return an Observable so when you subscribe to the observable the observer receives an object of ResponseType.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // pass postbody object from your component to service method, so service will read 
 // parameter value in reqBody .
 //Then it will pass to post call API 

 let postBody = {
        "overviewPreferences": {
            "selectedRole": [{
                "code": "PRACTITIONER"
            }],
            "selectedDomainList": [{
                "code": "2",
                "name": "HR"
            },
            {
                "code": "3",
                "name": "PAYROLL"
            }]
          }
 } 

servicename.updateUserSelectedDomains(postBody).subscribe( (response)=>{
       console.log(response);
 })




// =============== Service code ====================
updateUserSelectedDomains(reqBody): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.post<UserDomain>(`/adpi/rest/core/v2/business- 
   intelligence/workers/${aoId}/preferences" `, reqBody)                    
}
```